# What is the word for reserving something for yourself before others do?

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context, slang

In English-speaking TV shows, characters sometimes say something similar to *dips* to say to other people they are taking something for themselves before others do.

Neither Google, Wiktionary or Urban Dictionary give positive results for this so the word may be misspelled.

What is the word and what is its origin?

Comment: Also, just for reference, you can 'bagsy' something - or call shotgun on it

Comment: @Smock I've only ever heard shotgun being used in relation to [riding shotgun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riding_shotgun) in a car. You can't say "shotgun that beer", well, [you can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgunning), but it's far from the meaning of "Dibs on that beer".

Comment: Where I come from, french Canada, we do say "shotgun that beer" or "shotgun the last donut" and many other things like that, it came from the car thing though.

Comment: @Manuki In French or English?

Comment: @AzorAhai In french. For example "Shotgun la chaise verte!" (shotgun the green chair!). If you want the passenger seat in a car you will say "Shotgun en avant" (shotgun in the front)

Comment: Relevant: https://youtu.be/5hmdmUm99ZQ

Comment: Since we're posting relevant links: Shotgun! https://youtu.be/4TMi9EMRyQc?t=71s

Comment: I actually edited the typo (dips/dibs) to avoid vast confusion going forward, since everything on the internet is reality forever.  I'm really not sure if this is the best thing (maybe just close the question otherwise, since it's a faulty premise?) obviously anyone who knows better feel free to edit again.

Comment: @Fattie I feel that your edit introduces more confusion than the original version. As I read it, I was greatly confused as to why a simple Google search did not give any results, as searching for "dibs" does is fact give the correct result from multiple sources. Maybe there is a better way to indicate that OP meant "dibs" but misheard it as "dips".

Comment: The question doesn't make sense to me after Fattie's edit. The question originally said "*dips*", and Fattie changed this to "*dibs*"; I submitted an edit request changing this to "a word similar to *dips*".

Comment: When I was in elementary school the shout was "I got it!"  Of course, you had to touch the object first.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The word you're hearing is actually [*dibs*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dibs):

> 2: claim, rights
>   // I have *dibs* on that piece of cake

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dibs#etymonline_v_8533) says it's a

> children's word to express a claim on something, 1915, originally U.S., apparently from earlier senses "a portion or share" and "money" (early 19c. colloquial), probably a contraction of dibstone "a knuckle-bone or jack in a children's game" (1690s), in which the first element is of unknown origin. The game consisted of tossing up small pebbles or the knuckle-bones of a sheep and catching them alternately with the palm and the back of the hand.

Comment: Glorfindel called dibs on this answer.

Comment: In UK English this would be 'bags', although *dibs* would probably be understood too.

Comment: @DJClayworth In my experience, the two are similar but not quite equivalent in all usage. One can have "first dibs" on something, but not "\*first bags". Conversely, one can say "bags not" to remove themselves from the list of potentially-responsible candidates ("bags not washing the dishes") while there is no such form of "\*dibs not".

Comment: "Bagsy" is more common than "bags" in my particular part of the UK.

Comment: I can’t seem to find it in the dictionary, but “shot” is pretty common in the US in my experience. (“I shot the first shower!”) Kind of like “bags” from DJClayworth’s comment, “shot” has a converse, “shot not.”

Comment: @Daniel That's interesting. I've never heard that. What part of the US are you from?

Comment: @GrahamBorland Interestingly, Enid Blyton's stories have the characters saying "bags I", which presumably would have been the more original form when she was a girl. Like you, I've only ever heard "bagsy". Having a son myself now, it's intriguing to hear some playground slang changing over time - the most notable version is "eeny-meeny-miny-mo" which when I was a kid was followed by "catch a nigger by the toe". In an all-white school in a village in northern England, with casually racist relatives, us kids didn't have the context to know better. :( Kids these days catch a "tiger" or "Tigger".

Comment: @Daniel Presumably "shot" is shortened from "shotgun", commonly shouted to claim the front passenger seat of a car? (itself a short form of "[riding shotgun"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riding_shotgun) - from when a stagecoach would have an armed guard sat next to the driver for protection)

Comment: @jpaugh, NY, so god only knows where it came from

Comment: @Daniel From the Northeast US, I've heard people call "shotgun" on road trips to claim "dibs" on the front passenger seat. Also heard it shortened to "shotty" and used in the general case for calling "dibs" on anything.

Comment: @HarrisonPaine _Riding shotgun_ is quite common throughout the US (where _shotgun_ refers to the actual location in the front passenger seat), but I haven’t heard it as the word used to ‘call’ that seat – at least no more than any other such preference can be used exclamatorily (“Back seat!” – “Window seat!”), with the “I call/want” part understood.

Comment: I remember 'bags'/'bagsy' from my childhood in northern England in the 1950's. Maybe coincidence, but in Sweden the equivalent term is 'pax', presumably declaring a peaceful claim on an object.

Comment: In 1950s south London kids often said **bags I** [something]

Comment: A finer point to the ‘shotgun’ method of claiming the front passenger seat is that it cannot be claimed until the vehicle in which it resides is within visual range. ‘Riding shotgun’ comes from the practice of armed stagecoach riders taking the seat next to the driver, whose hands were busy with the reins and could not defend against highwaymen or other malefactors.

Comment: @DavidR Similarly, the Danish equivalent is _helle (for)_, where _helle_ is literally ‘sanctuary’ or ‘holy/free place’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It was the similarity in sound between the English and Swedish expressions that drew my attention, but I can't find anything to support any etymological link.

Answer (score 9):

Although "*bagsy*" and "*dibs*" are the two terms I know best, another phrase that has a similar meaning is "***two's up***".

I first heard it on an episode of the UK TV show "*QI*" hosted by Stephen Fry. From the [Transcript of Series 4, Episode 4](https://sites.google.com/site/qitranscripts/transcripts/4x04):

> **Stephen**
>   Yeah. Yeah. [working class accent] "*Two’s up on your burn.*"
>
> **Phill**
>   Two’s up on your burn?
>
> **Stephen**
>   "*Two’s up.*"
>
> **Phill**
>   I swear I’m getting an erection.
>
> **Stephen**
>   I have to say when I first arrived in prison, I was a little discombobulated by the entire experience, as you can imagine; you have to give your finger prints and take your clothes off and it’s all very . . . It’s just like public school, it’s lovely. But the . . . the first person who came in; he said, "*Two’s up.*" I said--[looks upward wonderingly]--"Is it? What? Where?" [working class accent] "*Two’s up. Two’s up, mate. Two’s up. On your burn.*"
>
> "*Two’s up*" means when you’ve finished your cigarette, you give it to the guy who’s first to say "*two’s up*" to you. And he gets the rights. It’s like saying "*bags have your fag end,*" basically. And then they collect about six of those and then they make a new cigarette out of it.

And, from the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=two%27s%20up), the currently top definition has:

> **Two's up** is a very old Yorkshire expression meaning, "*Save me a small amount of what you're currently consuming*" It was originally used by miners who were hungry and wanted a piece of pie from one of their more fortunate colleagues. It became more popular in the 70's and meant "share your cigarette with me":
>
> "*I've left my fags at home, two's up on your rolly (hand rolled cigarette)*"

And finally, the site [ARRSEPedia](https://www.arrse.co.uk/wiki/Two%27s_Up) (an informal, not 100% serious Wiki about anything connected to the British Army) has:

> Popular amongst capwearing bus-stop dwellers, meaning to leave half of a cigarette for someone else. A chav equivilent of puting dibs on something.

(It should, perhaps, be noted that both the Urban Dictionary and ARRSEPedia include alternative, somewhat less salubrious, uses for "*two's-up*", although the meaning is broadly similar).

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that "_chav_" would be considered offensive by many people, as well as the whole of that ARRSEPedia quote being pretty condescending and patronising 

Comment: I have never, ever heard this !

Answer (score 5):

The Oxford English Dictionary explains that to "get *dibs* on something" is to announce that one is making a first claim on something, the earliest recorded usage dating from 1932. Interestingly, the associated word *dubs* which relates to announcing a claim to two marbles knocked out of the playing ring, is recorded as being used more than a century prior to *dibs*. Not surprisingly, given the sound of *dubs*, it derives from the earlier cry of *doubles*.

Answer (score 1):

A related word you may encounter is "shotgun", which is effectively "calling dibs" but pertaining to the (desirable) front passenger seat in a car.

It has nothing to do with weapons, [but it used to.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shotgun#Noun)

Answer (score 1):

'shotgun'
'shotty'
'dibs'

All three are indicators of first in line status for anything in short supply. Interchangeable here in mid New England. e.g. "Dibs/shotty/shotgun that last cookie."

When subsequent argument about ownership occurs... "Well, I dibsed/shotgunned/shottied it first..."  are heard as proof.